# List providers enabled for an ETW trace event session in .NET

Tags: .net, etw, perfview

The logman tool can list all providers currently enabled for a running trace event session, e.g.:

```
logman query -ets SleepStudyTraceSession
```

How is that achieved in code using the TraceEvent library?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TraceEventSession.GetActiveSessionNames();`.

Here's an example:

```
  var sessions = TraceEventSession.GetActiveSessionNames();

            foreach (var session in sessions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(session);
            }
```

Comment: That will get the session names, not the providers enabled for a specific session. Presumably I could perhaps attach to a running session and maybe find out. Since the question is almost 4 years old at the time of writing this, I kind of forgot the exact reason. :-)